# How to catch an empty Vuex Store state but have a computed property react to it when initialized

Tags: vue.js, vuex, undefined

I am working on a Project in Vue Storefront with Vuex.

I have the following element to sort products in my webshop

```
      <SfSelect
        class="navbar__select sort-by"
        ref="SortBy"
        :selected="selectedSorting"
        @change="setSortingAttribute"
      >
        <SfSelectOption
          v-for="attribute in getSortingAttributes"
          :key="attribute.id"
          :value="attribute.title"
          class="sort-by__option"
          @click="setSelectedSortingAttribute(attribute)"
        >
          {{ attribute.title }}
        </SfSelectOption>
      </SfSelect>
```

Where           `v-for="attribute in getSortingAttributes"` does a for-loop on all available filters.

These filters are called from the Vuex Store State via the following computed property:

```
getSortingAttributes: function () {
  if (store.state.tweakwise.tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes
      .properties.sortfields
  ) {
    var tempSortAttributes =
      this.$store.state.tweakwise.tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes
        .properties.sortfields;

    return tempSortAttributes;
  }
},
```

This array is in the Vuex Store (tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes.properties.sortfields) where .poperties is an object in the array. The array is filled via an API call, this call is trigged via a Mount() in the same class as the SfSelect function, which I mentioned above.

Eventhough i added an `if-statement` to the `getSortingAttributes` to prevent it from calling undefined data and made it a computed property (to call it as soon as the data is available), I still get the following error:

Error during render : CategoryX/SubcategoryY/

TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortfields' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add safeguard(s) to your code - either using the new [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) or the old-school boolean OR:

```js
getSortingAttributes() 
{
  return this.$store.state.tweakwise?.tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes?.properties?.sortfields || [];
},
```

```js
getSortingAttributes() 
{
  return (((this.$store.state.tweakwise || {}).tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes || {}).properties || {}).sortfields || [];
},
```

Comment: That seems to be removing the undefined error! Do you, by chance, have any idea how I extend this with the computed property to still return the: this.$store.state.tweakwise?.tweakwiseLayeredNavigationAttributes?.properties?.sortfields

after it has been intialised?

I tried throwing all my functions in the mount() function, even though these are properties, they wont react at state change. Just once from the mount() trigger

Comment: I think that it would be better if you use a Vuex getter instead of computed property in the component. And it also depends at some degree on how you update the given object inside the Vuex store.